# sql tricky query with distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help me rewrite this query without a distinct clause?

```
   select     
       a.rec_type ,
       count(distinct a.a_tel_id) as count_distinct,       
       a.time_key as hour 
   from v_f_view as a with (nolock)
   group by rec_type,time_key
```

I foud with the execution plans that this query takes too long and I want to optimize it.

query plan : http://postimage.org/image/p1myi9tw/

Comment: If you need DISTINCT, you need DISTINCT. Maybe an index could help?

Comment: This would be as fast as you could get it. How does the execution plan look like? Did you add appropriate indexes?

Comment: What about v_f_view?  If that view is slow, then it may be causing the performance problems.

Comment: what do you by "the view is slow"? The tables contained in the view are properly indexed.

Comment: @Corovei - Could you show us the execution plan?

Comment: Please see the query plan link. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Indexes

Your problem is not the `DISTINCT` clause but the lack of indexes. The `DISTINCT` clause could be replaced by two `GROUP BY` clauses but this will most likely suffer the same performance penalty.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  a.rec_type
        , COUNT(*) as count_distinct
        , a.time_key as hour
FROM    (        
          SELECT a.rec_type
                  , a.a_tel_id
                  , a.time_key
          FROM    v_f_Logicacdrs21 a        
          GROUP BY
                  a.rec_type
                  , a.a_tel_id
                  , a.time_key
        ) a                  
GROUP BY
        a.rec_type
        , a.time_key
```

Comment: this is a worst solution in terms of execution time but it is a good trick to remember. Thx :D

Comment: On a properly indexed table, I wouldn't expect this to perform that much worse than the distinct clause but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I got something like 3 mins with distinct and 3 : 20 with your solution so the results are close.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have  `rec_type,time_key` indexed as a key? This is a must.

Comment: adding a_tel_id as the third index column might also be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

If a_tel_id has duplicates and you want to count them as one, then you can't optimize it by somehow magically remove **distinct**.

You might try to add index on the columns on which you group by.